# Can we check multiple values in single ternary condition?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Can we write the code like this in js to check the condition

```
input != (null || undefined) ? document.write(input) : document.write("Not Found");
```

I'm expecting to check whether the input is null or undefined

Comment: `(input != null || input != undefined) ? ... : ... `  But since `document.write` is not an expression that returns a value, you can also use a normal `if/else` block, no need for the ternary.

Comment: You need to put all condition inside a (conditions)  ? ... : ...

Comment: You could do `document.write(input ? input : "Not Found")` if null and undefined are the only possible [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values for `input`. But, this will write `Not Found` if input is an empty string or 0 (type number not "0")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're doing is not right,

```
input != (null || undefined)
```

This will always be treated as

```
input !=  undefined
```

because `||` logical OR always returns first truthy value if there's any if not than returns the last value

You can do it either

```
input != null || input != undefined
```

or you can

```
[null,undefined].some(val => val != input)
```